# DB2 SQL query returns some type of converted results when exporting to file

Tags: sql, db2, export

have shell script which queries a DB2 db and exports the output to a file. When I sun the SQL statement without exporting, I get the following:

```
su - myid -c 'db2 connect to mydb;db2 -v "select COL1"; db2 connect reset;'
```

**Sample Output**

```
COL 1
x'20A0E2450080000'
x'50D24520E100GDS00'
x'10H0EFJ10080000'
x'50A0GH0080000'
x'80RHE1008B0000'
x'70A50E1F4008000'
x'10F329EF09BB0'
```

But when I export my results using the exact same query, I get the following:

```
su - myid -c 'db2 connect to mydb;db2 -v "EXPORT TO '/tmp/query_results.out' OF DEL MODIFIED BY COLDEL: select COL1 from MYTABLE"; db2 connect reset;'
```

**Sample Output**

```
hôª"
"xàÓ °á
"èÅ °á
hôª"
"é# °á
hôª"
"é« °á
hôª"
"éÅ °á
hôª"
"""ÒYá   á
hôª"
"#sYá    á
hôª"
```

I'm assuming this is due to the single quote characters. Due to the fact that they are both preceded by another character, I have not been able to add '\' in front of them. I've also attempted to run the substr function within the query, but I still get the same result, only shorter. I'm sure there must be something I am overlooking, so after a several days of trying on my own (and failing), I'm turning to you guys. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*Edit: Just wanted to add that my actual select statement includes more than one column which are displayed correctly. So out of several columns, only one is displaying bad data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*I'm assuming this is due to the single quote characters*" -- No. This particular column contains binary data, either BLOB or VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA. If it is BLOB, specify LOBS TO in the EXPORT command, this way BLOBs will be written to binary files. If it is VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA, you can either convert it to BLOB on export (`export to ... lobs to ... select blob(your_column)...`) or export it as `hex(your_column)`, depending on what you're planning to do with the export later.

Another alternative for VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA would be to export your table using the IXF format instead of DEL, which will preserve binary strings.

Comment: Wow, I was really off the mark. Thank you, I'll try this now. BTW, this column's datatype is RAW. I don't know if that makes a difference. @mustaccio

Comment: BTW, there is no RAW data type in DB2 as far as I know. It has to be either (VAR)CHAR FOR BIT DATA or BLOB.